# Find duplicate value in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have the following array:

```
let items = [
                {"Item":"1","OfficeID":"82388","Title":"Bamboozled"},
                {"Item":"2","OfficeID":"82392","Title":"Malarkey"},
                {"Item":"3","OfficeID":"65747","Title":"Flabbergasted"},
                {"Item":"4","OfficeID":"82390","Title":"Cattywampus"},
                {"Item":"5","OfficeID":"77091","Title":"Lollygag"},
                {"Item":"6","OfficeID":"81726","Title":"Kerfuffle"},
                {"Item":"7","OfficeID":"82155","Title":"Brouhaha"},
                {"Item":"8","OfficeID":"82265","Title":"Skedaddle"},
                {"Item":"8","OfficeID":"82394","Title":"Nincompoop"},
                {"Item":"10","OfficeID":"82395","Title":"Tomfoolery"}
            ]
```

There is a repeated Item: 8

I would like to find the duplicate/repeated Item(s) value(s) so that I can use that information and return it to a message for the user. How can this be done using JavaScript. Any examples are appreciated.

Thank you

*UPDATE*

Work around to my problem. Adding it to this question, in the event that someone might have a smiliar question/issue, and lands in this forum.

```
const array = [
                {"Agenda":"1","OfficeID":"82388","Title":"Bamboozled"},
                {"Agenda":"2","OfficeID":"82392","Title":"Malarkey"},
                {"Agenda":"3","OfficeID":"65747","Title":"Flabbergasted"},
                {"Agenda":"4","OfficeID":"82390","Title":"Cattywampus"},
                {"Agenda":"5","OfficeID":"77091","Title":"Lollygag"},
                {"Agenda":"6","OfficeID":"81726","Title":"Kerfuffle"},
                {"Agenda":"7","OfficeID":"82155","Title":"Brouhaha"},
                {"Agenda":"8","OfficeID":"82265","Title":"Skedaddle"},
                {"Agenda":"8","OfficeID":"82394","Title":"Nincompoop"},
                {"Agenda":"10","OfficeID":"82395","Title":"Tomfoolery"}
            ];

const result = [];
let prevName = null;
let count = 0;

array.forEach(item => {
  if (item.Agenda === prevName) {
    count++;
  } else {
    if (count > 1) {
      for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        result.push(prevName);
      }
    }
    prevName = item.Agenda;
    count = 1;
  }
});



console.log('result:', result);
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have not tried anything yet. I have been looking for some examples online but I have not been successful in finding anything that checks for a similar duplicate like in my array. I was hoping to get some dieas in here, but my question was closed.

Comment: SO isn't a coding service. How would you do this by hand? Think about that process and how you would translate it to JS

Comment: My bad, sorry for the mistake.